# Where can I find the error logs when an application crashes?

Tags: applications, appcenter, release-juno

In order to ask a better question for my issue about the [AppCenter crashing on viewing app details](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16936/appcenters-crashes-when-looking-at-installed-application-details) I would like to paste some of the logs when the AppCenter crashes.

Where can I find said error logs for AppCenter or other applications in elementary OS 5 (Juno)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`journalctl -xe
cat /var/log/syslog`